# Visual Fox Pro Query join error in php - odbc_exec

Tags: php, sql, odbc, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I have this query written in php:

```
<?php
$dsn="sistema";
$usuario="";
$clave="";
/*conexion mediante odbc*/
$cid=odbc_connect($dsn, $usuario, $clave);
if (!$cid){
exit("<strong>Ya ocurrido un error tratando de conectarse con el origen de datos.  </strong>");
}
$sql="SELECT SUM(Document.docimp) AS sumar FROM Document WHERE Doctpo IN ('1','6','7') AND Document.Abocod = 1";
$sql1="SELECT SUM(Document.docimp) AS restar FROM Document WHERE Doctpo IN ('2','3') AND Document.Abocod = 1";
$sql3="Select (A.sumar - A.restar) AS Saldo; 
From (;
Select Document.abocod,;
      (SELECT SUM(Document.docimp) AS sumar;
    FROM Document; 
    WHERE Doctpo IN ('1','6','7'); 
        AND Document.Abocod = 1;
    ),;
    (SELECT SUM(Document.docimp) AS restar ;
    FROM Document; 
    WHERE Doctpo IN ('2','3'); 
        AND Document.Abocod = 1;
    );
From; Document;
Where Document.abocod = 1;
GROUP BY Document.abocod;
)AS A";
$result=odbc_exec($cid,$sql)or die(exit("Error en odbc_exec"));
print odbc_result_all($result,"Border=1"););
?>
```

The `sql` takes from Document table, all files of type 1,6 and 7 from Doctpo field, doing a `sum` of what's in `Docimp` field, filtering by subscriber number (abocod) equal to 1 and placing the result with it's name (alias).

The `sql1` same function as `sql`, but here is the payment made by customers, using the same fields as above but selecting only type 2 and 3.

`sql3` is a query that joins the `sql` and `sql1` in a single query, and executes all the functions that were made separately by `sql` and `sql1`.

Queries (SQL) work perfectly when I run them into visual fox pro, but when I execute them from php, `sql` and `sql1` do work, but it always throws errors with the `sql3` statement. Saying that table is not recognized or doesn't exist.

I can't figure out how it can't make the join with these tables, if this works perfectly on Visual foxpro itself.

I would like to know if there is a 'cleaner' or 'better' approach with php, odbc and visual fox pro.

Anyone can shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just running the query once through instead of two seperate, then joining...  Something like

```
select
      sum( 0000.00 + iif( Doctpo in ( '1', '6', '7' ), Document.docimp, 0 )) as Sumar,
      sum( 0000.00 + iif( Doctpo in ( '2', '3' ), Document.docimp, 0 )) as Restar,
      sum( Document.docimp * iif( Doctpo in ( '1', '6', '7' ), 1, -1 )) as Saldo
   from
      FROM Document; 
   WHERE 
          Document.Abocod = 1;
      AND Doctpo IN ('1','6','7', '2', '3');
```

I'm doing a sum of 0000.00 + IIF() because whatever the first value is returned from a VFP query is the basis of that column type in final set.  So, you may need to adjust the default length/precision per your needs if you will expect any balance above 9999.99.

Comment: Sorry for the silly question, Can i use 'iif()' from php over odbc_connect?

Comment: @KristianKoci, I believe so, much like in other languages you can use LEFT(), RIGHT(), IF(), its just that in VFP, IIF() is valid.